# How to multi-thread wait for user input and do other things before user input

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make a simple time zone dashboard based on the command line. This dashboard allows the user to switch to the "Add or Remove Time Zones" page to add or remove time zones when the space bar is pressed. I plan to refresh the current system time at the top of the screen every second. I found some ways to control the cursor with ctypes, which is very useful.

However, after the program switches to the Add or Remove Time Zones page, how do I refresh the top time while waiting for the user to complete the input? Because "Input" needs to wait for user input, so it seems like no way to do that. (But C++'s Qt can do multi-threaded refreshing of the user interface, so I think Python should be able to do something similar, too.)

Since the book "Python Crash Course:: A Hands-On, Project-Based Introduction to Programming" does not cover multi-threaded programming, so I searched for some articles and cases and modified the code.

The following is the code I wrote (I am not very familiar with multithreading, the multithreaded code is someone else's code I copied).

This is not a complete code, it is just a test.

```py
import ctypes
import time
import threading
class COORD(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("X", ctypes.c_short), ("Y", ctypes.c_short)]

STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE= -11
std_out_handle = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
dwCursorPosition = COORD()
dwCursorPosition.X = 3
dwCursorPosition.Y = 3
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleCursorPosition(std_out_handle,dwCursorPosition)
i=1
class waiting(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.thread_stop = False
        global dwCursorPosition
        dwCursorPosition.X = 1
        dwCursorPosition.Y = 1
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleCursorPosition(std_out_handle,dwCursorPosition)
        s = input("Hi!Input Something!")
    def stop(self):
        self.thread_stop = True
class refresh(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.thread_stop = False
        global dwCursorPosition,i
        dwCursorPosition.X = 3
        dwCursorPosition.Y = 3
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleCursorPosition(std_out_handle,dwCursorPosition)
        i += 1
        print("Refresh!!{}".format(i))
    def stop(self):
        self.thread_stop = True

while True:
    thread1 = refresh()
    thread2 = waiting()
    thread1.start()

    thread2.start()
    thread1.stop()
    thread2.stop()
```

I want the number after "Refresh" to be refreshed while waiting for my input. But this does not seem to work.